# Typescript React: Conditionally mark prop to optional or mandatory using another prop passed to same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript react. While I am working on this I have encountered a problem that is marking prop to optional or mandatory using another prop passed to same component.

something like

```
export type abcProps = {
a?:boolean,
b?:boolean
}
```

if b prop is false then a should be mandatory other a should be optional. How do I achieve this.

I have checked multiple block but could not understand much. Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
type MyType =  { a: boolean, b: false } | { a?: boolean, b: true }

let foo: MyType = { b: true }
let baz: MyType = { b: false, a: true }
let baz2: MyType = { b: false, a: false }
let shouldError: MyType = { b: false } // compilation error
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDNQI1AHATge3hAzqSBDANugU1ABcALAgO1G1HVOQFdcATWIgW2wue2OUQCeoZGQKJqtek1YwiqYuGQU8AOlAAJZAHdQzZKACS1AMalwBAG5Ey4dCoCwAKCfEB8IgFkBAFTdEAvKCgAN7UAFywyMi4BFwANLAROPhEAL6gAD4h1AD8ETBRMfGJJIgMaU5OMcRYURFevu6ggaEwEcRlFY7VsNgAXvU+fs3ZbVh4hAnY7Z2gqVUENTD9AEyDjQGjSRMEU9spcws1dIwsAKKIKIjrwy0lyYRzQA)

Basically, you define your variable to be of two types

- A type where `b` is false and `a` is a boolean
- A type where `b` is true and `a` is an optional boolean

Comment: if I have more props as in 10 or 20 props duplicating all of them in two different objects will be lot of duplicate code right?

Comment: it depends all the combinations you want to do. You can probably split the unchanged properties into a separated type and combine them.

Comment: You can also take advantage of the utility types in order to avoid repeating all the properties: You could use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) and [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to get all the properties you want to make optional

Comment: Can you please provide code for it how to achieve in case of multiple props? Thanks

Comment: yes, but please update your question with a realistic scenario so I can do exactly what you need